# Fill the value from other tow dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table look like this

```py
   Upper    Lower
0    1        4
1    4        3
2    0        4
3    2        1
4    4        2
```

And I want to fill the `Upper` and `Lower` by these two series below

```py
df1:
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
4  E

df2:
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  e
```

So, the answer would like

```
   Upper    Lower
0    B        e
1    E        d
2    A        e
3    C        b
4    E        c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by both `Series`:

```
df['Upper'] = df['Upper'].map(df1)
df['Lower'] = df['Lower'].map(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative way -**

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
upper = np.array([1, 4, 0, 2, 4], dtype=int)
lower = np.array([4,3,4,1,2], dtype=int)

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Upper': upper,
'Lower': lower,
})
df['Upper']= df['Upper']+65
df['Lower']= df['Lower']+97
df=df.applymap(chr)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Upper Lower
0     B     e
1     E     d
2     A     e
3     C     b
4     E     c
```